# How to reduce CPU usage in requestAnimationFrame() method

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, marquee, requestanimationframe

Here is my code for **marquee text** with medium speed. This is good in Performance wise, But im getting 50% of CPU usage. anyone can please help me to reduce the CPU usage.

```js
const content = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
const elWidth = content.offsetWidth;

let progress = 1;
let speed = 4;
function loop() {

    progress = progress - speed;
    if (progress <= elWidth * -1) {
        progress = 0;
    }
    container.style.transform = 'translateX(' + progress + 'px)';
    container.style.transform += 'skewX(' + speed * 0.4 + 'deg)';
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

> Please suggest is any other way to reduce CPU usage using javascript

[image]

Comment: Could you show, how you calculate `elWidth`? Is it calculate in the each step? If you are using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` — it can be a reason of high CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay,

const content = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
const elWidth = content.offsetWidth;

This code is outside my loop in the beginning

Comment: what cpu do you have?

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem here, but avoid concatenation of setters by doing `+=`, directly do `= val1 + val2`. Then, there is nothing that should consume too much in this part of the code, but what this code internally triggers may be intensive, depending on what's rendered. What if you use the performance inspector in your dev tools, can't you find what's causing this CPU usage?

Comment: Actually Im testing it in my TV device
Arm 64GB processor im using here
Please check the image attachment

Comment: Please find the CPU configuration 
OS Linux
CPU ARM Cortex A9 1.2GHz Quad Core